# How to send email when customer cancel payment?

Tags: commerce, rules, emails

I am using Drupal Commerce 7x-1.10 and PayPal WPS 7.x-2.3 module. How can I send an email to customer (both anonymous and authenticate), if they cancel the order or cancel the payment method or cancel anytime within the checkout process?

I am using rules, also I have use "cancelled" in the Condition section. But for some reason it is not working. Please see below for the rules code -

```
{ "rules_completing_the_checkout" : {
    "LABEL" : "Completing the checkout",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "mimemail", "commerce_checkout" ],
    "ON" : { "commerce_checkout_complete" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "commerce-order:status" ], "value" : "canceled" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "mimemail" : {
          "key" : [ "commerce-order:mail" ],
          "to" : [ "commerce-order:mail" ],
          "cc" : [ "" ],
          "subject" : "Cancel Order? Why",
          "body" : "Cancel Order? Why",
          "plaintext" : "Cancel Order? Why",
          "language" : [ "commerce-order:state" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can implement it via the module [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)

Just add the action "Send email" for a custom rule that has the "order state changes" event conditionally on order state "cancelled."

Comment: Yes, I am using rules. I have edited my question and given the rules code, please check it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you found any solution to this?
If not, here's what you can do....

1. Create a module with custom event `hook_rules_event_info`
2. Implement `hook_redirect_form_back` and `hook_process_callback` in your payment gateway
3. Use `rules_invoke_event` in your above method to execute the rule.
4. Use Rules UI to create new rule with the above event and send mail as action.

Example:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_rules_event_info()
 */
function YOURMODULE_rules_event_info() {
    return array(
        'commerce_payment_canceled_event' => array(
            'label' => t('Commerce payment canceled'),
            'module' => 'YOURMODULE',
            'group' => 'Any group' ,
            'variables' => array(
                'commerce_order' => array(
                    'type' => 'commerce_order',
                    'label' => t('Completed order', array(), array('context' => 'a drupal commerce order')),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
}

    /**
     * + * Payment method callback: redirect form back callback.
     * + */
    function PAYMENTGATEWAY_redirect_form_back($order, $payment_method)
    {
        // Display a message indicating the customer canceled payment.
        //Can also be done in rule via set system message and level set to error    
        drupal_set_message(t('You have canceled payment but may resume the checkout process here when you are ready.'), 'error');

        // If you wish to reset selected payment while redirecting
        unset($order->data['payment_method']);

        // Process callback information from gateway.
        return PAYMENTGATEWAY_process_callback($order, $payment_method);
    }

    function PAYMENTGATEWAY_process_callback($order, $payment_method)
    {
        rules_invoke_event('commerce_payment_canceled_event', $order);

    }
```

Found this base idea from someone using Ogone payment gateway.